# Funciones con parametros C++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer un juego de cartas en el que dos jugadores ingresan 5 cartas cada uno, despues se comprueba la mayor de cada uno y cuantas veces se repite. Debo almacenarlo con funciones y esta es la manera que se me ha ocurrido pero no consigo almacenar las cartas y luego mostrarlas

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pedirDatos(int primerJ[], int segundoJ[], int MAX_CARTAS);
int mayorYrepetida(int primerJ[], int *masAlta, int MAX_CARTAS);

const int MAX_CARTAS = 5;

void main() {

int primerJ[MAX_CARTAS], segundoJ[MAX_CARTAS];
int masAlta = 0;
int resultado;

pedirDatos(primerJ, segundoJ, MAX_CARTAS);

resultado = mayorYrepetida(primerJ, &masAlta, MAX_CARTAS);
cout << "La carta mas alta del jugador 1 es: " << masAlta << endl;
cout << "Y se repite " << resultado << " veces. \n";

system("pause");
}

void pedirDatos(int primerJ[], int segundoJ[], int MAX_CARTAS) {

// Pedir datos primer jugador
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CARTAS; i++)
{
    cout << "Que el jugador 1 introduzca sus cartas \n";
    do
    {
        cout << "Carta numero " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> primerJ[i];
        if (primerJ[i] < 1 || primerJ[i] > 12)
        {
            cout << "Valor incorrecto, solo se acepta del 1 al 12. \n";
        }
    } while (primerJ[i] < 1 || primerJ[i] > 12);

}
// Pedir datos segundo jugador
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CARTAS; i++)
{
    cout << "Que el jugador 2 introduzca sus cartas \n";
    do
    {
        cout << "Carta numero " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> segundoJ[i];
        if (segundoJ[i] < 1 || segundoJ[i] > 12)
        {
            cout << "Valor incorrecto, solo se acepta del 1 al 12. \n";
        }
    } while (segundoJ[i] < 1 || segundoJ[i] > 12);
}
} 
int mayorYrepetida(int primerJ[], int *masAlta, int MAX_CARTAS) {

int *masAlta = 0;
int contador = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CARTAS; i++)
{
    if (primerJ[i] > *masAlta)
    {
        *masAlta = primerJ[i];
    }
    if (primerJ[i] == *masAlta)
    {
        contador++;
    }
}
return contador;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int mayorYrepetida(int primerJ[], int *masAlta, int MAX_CARTAS) {
//                                    ^^^^^^^^

  int *masAlta = 0; // <<---
```

Fíjate en el fragmento de código anterior... estás declarando `masAlta` **dos veces**. Entiendo que tu intención aquí es inicializar el argumento `masAlta` y para eso tienes que borrar el segundo `int`:

```
int mayorYrepetida(int primerJ[], int *masAlta, int MAX_CARTAS) {

  *masAlta = 0; // <<--- Ya no declaramos variable
```

Por cierto, nota que cada vez que actualizas `masAlta` tienes que reiniciar `contador` ya que si no vas a obtener un número de repeticiones incorrecto:

```
if (primerJ[i] > *masAlta)
{
    *masAlta = primerJ[i];
    contador = 0;
}
```